# Move multiple pdf files to folders with same name

Tags: batch-file

All,
I would like to set up a script to move pdf files from one folder into their corresponding folder that is setup inside another folder.
The pdfs are invoices that get saved with a PO name ex: P32081 in a folder named mailbox.
These all need to be moved to their corresponding file that resides in another folder but the file name is slightly different that it needs to go into ex- 757-P32081 MEDLINE.
Rather than drag and drop one by one for hundreds of these, I would like a script in notepad to do it.
I don’t have admin rights to use programs or powershell.
The pdfs will always move from the mailbox folder into their file inside order received folder.
Each user is setup this way. Any help would be appreciated.
All files and folders are on the same drive, ex J: drive

Comment: Are you allowed to run cmd? In this case you can create a batch/cmd file. To run cmd, try WIN+R type cmd, then ENTER key.

Comment: I will check but I doubt it, it’s the government.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess they've done their job. If you can't run any program (like AutoHotKey), Powershell or batch, then I don't see how you could automate this or anything, very sorry :-( Could you contact them about this specific problem, and maybe get an authorization on "something"?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I can run like a batch from notepad